# Getting invalid QModelIndex from QTableWidget in some occasions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using the cursor position to get the cell the cursor is selecting and then use that to decide what the context menu should have. But, on small tables, for example with only 2 rows, i get a lot of invalid indexes, causing this to return None and a subsequent fail. If i fullscreen the app, it works on the top left cell, but not any others. I have very little understanding of why this happens, and i really hope people can reproduce the same issue here with this example, where i am experiencing it.

```
import traceback

from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidget, QMenu, QApplication, QTableWidgetItem

import sys


class TableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):

        cursor = QCursor.pos()

        index = self.indexAt(cursor)
        try:
            column = self.itemFromIndex(index).column()
            menu = QMenu(self)
            if column:
                menu.addAction('TEST')
            else:
                menu.addAction('Fail')
            menu.exec(QCursor.pos())
        except Exception as e:
            traceback.print_exc()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = TableWidget()
    gui.setColumnCount(3)
    gui.insertRow(0)
    gui.insertRow(0)
    gui.insertRow(0)
    gui.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem('0'))
    gui.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem('0'))
    gui.setItem(2, 0, QTableWidgetItem('0'))
    gui.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem('0'))
    gui.setItem(0, 2, QTableWidgetItem('0'))
    gui.setItem(1, 1, QTableWidgetItem('0'))
    gui.setItem(1, 2, QTableWidgetItem('0'))

    gui.show()
    app.exec()
```

The try/except is just to showcase that it's going to break, and give this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/THOMAS/PycharmProjects/Scripts/test2.py", line 17, in contextMenuEvent
    column = self.itemFromIndex(index).column()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'column'
```

Because the QModelindex is invalid. (Checked with .isValid())

I also tried using `self.itemAt(cursor)` with the exact same results. I get None except for when i'm fullscreen and in cell 0, 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

error in this line:

```
cursor = QCursor.pos ()
```

change to:

```
cursor = event.pos ()
```

Try it:

```
import traceback

from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidget, QMenu, QApplication, QTableWidgetItem

import sys


class TableWidget(QTableWidget):

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):

        #cursor = QCursor.pos()
        cursor = event.pos()

        index = self.indexAt(cursor)

        try:
            column = self.itemFromIndex(index).column()
            menu = QMenu(self)
            if column:
                menu.addAction('TEST')
            else:
                menu.addAction('Fail')

            menu.exec(QCursor.pos())
        except Exception as e:
            traceback.print_exc()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = TableWidget()
    gui.setColumnCount(3)
    gui.insertRow(0)
    gui.insertRow(0)
    gui.insertRow(0)
    gui.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem('0'))
    gui.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem('0'))
    gui.setItem(2, 0, QTableWidgetItem('0'))
    gui.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem('0'))
    gui.setItem(0, 2, QTableWidgetItem('0'))
    gui.setItem(1, 1, QTableWidgetItem('0'))
    gui.setItem(1, 2, QTableWidgetItem('0'))

    gui.show()
    app.exec()
```

[image]